# I am a issue with jQuery move element according to mouse pointer move

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to do something like when the mouse will moves left to right or right to left the middle will move according to the mouse pointer inside the circle. but I can't. here is my code

circle size 180deg

more  reference here is the image
[image]

```js
 $(document).on("click mousemove", ".circle", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var angel = Math.round(Math.atan2(x, y) * (180 / Math.PI))
  $(".needle").css("transform", "rotate(" + angel + "deg)");
});
```

```css
#needle {
  width: 6px;
  height: 83px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(345deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 116px;
  top: 44px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
   <div id="needle" class="needle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! You whaat? :) Pleas try to split up your long introduction sentence to two or three clear short statements, so we can have a chance to get what you are trying to tell us. And please be specific. thanks

Comment: thanks, @helle .    I am trying to make a function. there is a 180deg circle and a needle.  I want to move the needle when we mouse over the circle according to the mouse move on the circle. hope you understand my problem.

Comment: In your demo you have two issues, first is that circle has 0 height, if you use `height: 100vh` you will be able to move the cursor and it will change. The second issue is that clientX and clientY are positions from the top left of the circle, not to the center. So maybe you have your math wrong, I'm not exactly sure what you want. You can try to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ if you have problems with trigonometry.